# Using objective-c clang static analyser

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++, xcodebuild, clang-static-analyzer

I've been trying to use [clang-analyze](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) without issues for 2 days.

I am using the following command:

```
checker-276/scabuild xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme AppScheme -configuration Debug clean build

scan-build: Using '/Users/abc/checker-276/bin/clang' for static analysis
Build settings from command line:
    CLANG_ANALYZER_EXEC = /Users/abc/checker-276/bin/clang
    CLANG_ANALYZER_OTHER_FLAGS = 
    CLANG_ANALYZER_OUTPUT = plist-html
    CLANG_ANALYZER_OUTPUT_DIR = /var/folders/5p/48jf5v4516l7x9dhb0vj6jr0prj25r/T/scan-build-2015-03-06-113904-24636-1
    RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER = YES
```

I've tried to play with the parameters, to set the sdk, build settings, compiler etc, however the final result is the same:

```
mylib.h:68:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
 fatal error: 'vector' file not found
#include <vector>
```

I am using several c++ library which are included in `.mm` files. I think that could be a problem, but XCode static analyser can do the job right, so I assume that I can configure also clang static analyser in way to do the job.

`xcodebuild` does the hard work(compilation) anyway why does scanbuild fails then?

Do you have any idea how I can eliminate the above mentioned issues?

I appreciate any advice, thanks for your time spending with it!